# Metrics of validation set are weird

Tags: validation, deep-learning, pytorch, crop, training-data

I'm doing a project about image processing by deep learning, and the question I am facing is that metrics of validation data set are much different with those of training data set. The difference is shown as below.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNw3m.png)
For the upper graph (training data set), the green, blue, red lines represent ms-ssim, loss of generator, and loss of discriminator respectively. 
For the lower graph (validatation data set), the blue, gray, orange lines represent ms-ssim, loss of generator, and loss of discriminator respectively. 
The only difference between these two data set is that validation set is unprocessed (1200*800) but training set is cropped (256*256).

Next, I attempt to crop validation set with the same setting. Just as what I guess, the metrics of two data set become similar. However, since the real images (testing data set) are not cropped, these metrics seem to be useless.

My question is :

1. Why 'cropping' can make such difference?
2. How can I make the metrics of two sets similar without cropping validation set?
3. Does it look like over-fitting?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to know what the exact task is. What are you trying to solve, how does your data look like ... .

In general it really makes a difference. You have 1200x800 as the raw input size and crop it to 256x256. So in the end you extracted a 256x256 region from a 1200x800 image. What and where do you even crop, just random or with some kind of logic?

This way you completely change the data distribution. The raw image will contain much more information. Depending on how the cropping is done the network might see information it has never seen before. You also go from a squared input to a rectangular one. A lot of models don't even work at all on such different input sizes.

If you can only train on the cropped images you have to crop the validation and test set too, in order to get comparable results.

Just from the information given it doesn't look like over fitting at all more like a problem with a big domain shift introduced by the image cropping.

Comment: My task is about multi-exposure fusion, input is 2 images with different exposure time and output is a fused image. Moreover, the images in data set are randomly cropped.
From your description, cropping training and validation sets seems to be more rational than keep validation set similar with real data.

Comment: I also have another problem. If my model is able to deal with cropped images, how can I make sure it is also able to deal with real data which is not cropped? Is there any keyword about this?

Comment: You can just crop the real world images, if this can be a sufficient solution. If you want to apply the network to real world data you should train it on data similar. If you don't do that you will have a domain shift, which is hard to solve and no general techniques exist for this. Also depends heavily on what you are actually doing.

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @quarterlift Hey if my answer was able to help you please consider voting and accepting it. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)